# "email" validation rule crash sails server - Mongo with Sails.js

Tags: sails.js, waterline

while the email validation rule fails on module of the sails.js, the server is crashing.
Here the snippet of my module:
  // The user's email address

```
email: {
  type: 'string',
  email: true,
  required: true,
  unique: true
},
```

And the error as below :

> err:  Error (E_VALIDATION) :: 1 attribute is invalid
>       at WLValidationError.WLError (C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\error\WLError.js:26:15)
>       at new WLValidationError (C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\error\WLValidationError.js:20:28)
>       at C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\validate.js:45:43
>       at allValidationsChecked (C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\core\validations.js:203:5)
>       at done (C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:135:19)
>       at C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:32:16
>       at C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\core\validations.js:184:23
>       at done (C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:135:19)
>       at C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:32:16
>       at C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\core\validations.js:157:64
>       at C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:125:13
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at _each (C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:46:24)
>       at Object.async.each (C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:124:9)
>       at validate (C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\core\validations.js:156:11)
>       at C:\Users\yuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:125:13
>   Invalid attributes sent to User:
>    • email
>      • `undefined` should be a email (instead of "admin@gmailasd", which is a string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to declare an email field is like this :

```
email: {
  type: 'email',
  required: true,//Email field will be required for insert or update  
  unique: true //Insert or update will crash if you try to insert duplicate email
},
```

You can see all different attribut types here http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes

If you want to catch insert/update errors you can do this on your controller :

```
MyModel.create({email:email}).exec(function(err, model)
{
     if(err)
     {
       //Check if it's a validation error or a crash 
       if(err.code == "E_VALIDATION")
         sails.log.debug("valid fail, check form");
       else 
         sails.log.debug("crash");
     }
     else
     {
       //do what you want to do with the data
     }
});
```

Comment: It is crushing still:(

Comment: Normal if you don't specify on email who is required validation throw an exception it's normal

Comment: If you don't want if just try catch your create/update method

Comment: Can i  add the exception handler on model? Or i should do this in Controller?

Comment: I think you can only do it on controller not on model

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Comment: email: true - it is no longer necessary. Only type: 'email'

Answer (score 2):

Her the answer.
Thanks to jaumard, i found the problem.
I used undefined field in error, without checking if exists before
err.originalError.code but it was undefined.
So the correct way is :
err.originalError && err.originalError.code && err.originalError.code === 11000

and not
err.originalError.code === 11000.

Answer (score 1):

Previous versions of Sails recommended that email validation was achieved like this

email: {
  type: 'string',
  email: true,
  required: true
},

The current version should be like this

email: {
  type: 'email',
  required: true
},

Comment: Filed [an issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/issues/588) for documentation on the `email` attribute.