# Sails' Waterline email validation always failed

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I was working on my application and all was ok, but after reinstalling system to Windows 10 i always have an email validation fail. I don't really think this happens because of Windows 10, but it's only thing that was changed.

For testing i have created new shiny model:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      email: true
    }
  }
}
```

And if i start application with `sails console` and type `TestModel.create({ email: 'alex@yahoo.com' }).exec(function(err, created) { console.log(err); console.log(created); })` i'll get something like this:

> Error (E_VALIDATION) :: 1 attribute is invalid
>       at WLValidationError.WLError (C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\error\WLError.js:26:15)
>       at new WLValidationError (C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\error\WLValidationError.js:20:28)
>       at C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\validate.js:46:43
>       at allValidationsChecked (C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\core\validations.js:210:5)
>       at C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:49:16
>       at done (C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:239:19)
>       at C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:40:16
>       at C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\core\validations.js:201:14
>       at C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:49:16
>       at done (C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:239:19)
>       at C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:40:16
>       at C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\core\validations.js:164:64
>       at C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:162:20
>       at C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:230:13
>       at _arrayEach (C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:81:9)
>       at _each (C:\Users\My name is Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:72:13)
>
> Invalid attributes sent to TestModel:
>    • email
>      • "email" validation rule failed for input: 'alex@yahoo.com'

If i disable email validation, all works nice.

```
{ email: 'alex@yahoo.com',
  createdAt: '2015-08-08T21:09:25.118Z',
  updatedAt: '2015-08-08T21:09:25.118Z',
  id: 1 }
```

Own email validation method - isn't good solution.

I tried trivial stupid things like database reinstall, but it doesn't helps. Sorry for my bad english, hope i'll find answer here.

Comment: If you would like an additional resource in the future, here is a chat room for sails.js, node.js, and waterline questions. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Answer (score 7):

I have one weird solution now. I changed attribute type to `'email'` and deleted `email: true` type.

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    }
  }
};
```

And now it works. It's ok for me, but it is doesn't documented and i still want to know why default way doesn't works.

Comment: Apparently, that IS the [proper](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29675901/1100528) way.

Comment: Yep - changing to this style worked for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [waterline docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline):

> Validations are defined directly in you Collection attributes. In addition you may set the attribute type to any supported Anchor type and Waterline will build a validation and set the schema type as a string for that attribute.

So when you set a type that is not one of the [core types](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/data-types-attributes.md) waterline will use it to validate the type in one of the validation [rules supported by Anchor](https://github.com/balderdashy/anchor/blob/master/lib/match/rules.js) and keep the data as string

Therefore defining the schema like this will work:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    }
  }
};
```